# Get return value of method in parallel execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, .net-4.0

I am using `Parallel.Invoke` to execute single method with different input values, but I want to get return value of the method.
How can I get it ?

```
public class Work
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(() => DoWork("Raju"),
                        () => DoWork("Ramu"));
    }

    public static string DoWork(string data)
    {
        return "testing" + data;
    }
}
```

In above method I want get `DoWork` return value.

Comment: Did you read this post? : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=491

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just handle the return value like this:

```
string result1, result2;

Parallel.Invoke(() => result1 = DoWork("Raju"),
                () => result2 = DoWork("Ramu"));
```

Also remember that whenever you do something in parallel you need to be careful to avoid data races and race conditions.