# C# execute shell command parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I want to run 3 shell commands in parallel and get the output/result. Any idea how I can implement this?

I tried already "Parallel.for..." but I cannot catch the output/result. Her is the example:

```
Parallel.For(0, 3, number => {
   arg1 = array3[number];
   process.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1 + arg2;
   process.Start();

   output[number] = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   process.WaitForExit();
   MessageBox.Show(output[number]);
});
```

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer besides "run Process.Start three times". Can you [edit] your post with what you've tried so far - such as a [mre].

Comment: I have added the code see above.

Comment: Possibly related: [Get return value of method in parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211957/get-return-value-of-method-in-parallel-execution), and [Awaiting multiple Tasks with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results).